# Creating a specific database deployment script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have been asked to migrate a schema from our testing area into our staging area.

As someone that has never done this before my first instinct would be to paste every script into one large script and hope that I have done it in the right order.

Is there a better way? If anyone could point me to this information I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Generate Script` option when right clicking on database in `Management Studio` and even choosing to export data to the file in last step by clicking the `Advanced` button.

A tutorial can be found here [How to: Generate a Script (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078.aspx)

Comment: The link takes me to SQL Server 2008. Is this also a feature of 2005?

Comment: Maybe it's just a function of SQL Server Management Studio which can be freely downloaded.

Comment: @user1016253: In MSDN SQLServer articles, there is usually a drop-down menu labelled "Other Versions" next to where it says which version of SQLServer is applicable to the page - if you click on it, you will get a list of hyperlinks to the documentation for the other versions. In this case, the equivalent SQLServer 2005 page is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx .